# Create multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a database query result that is an array and it looks like as below:

```
[{"uid":29,"totalAmount":"5400.00"},
 {"uid":499,"totalAmount":"5400.00"},
 {"uid":507,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
 {"uid":497,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
 {"uid":498,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
 {"uid":34,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
 {"uid":21,"totalAmount":"3240.00"},
 {"uid":27,"totalAmount":"2880.00"},
 {"uid":500,"totalAmount":"2880.00"},
 {"uid":19,"totalAmount":"2700.00"},
 {"uid":22,"totalAmount":"2700.00"},
 {"uid":20,"totalAmount":"2520.00"},
 {"uid":23,"totalAmount":"2520.00"},
 {"uid":504,"totalAmount":"1800.00"},
 {"uid":496,"totalAmount":"1440.00"},
 {"uid":26,"totalAmount":"1260.00"},
 {"uid":491,"totalAmount":"1080.00"},
 {"uid":492,"totalAmount":"720.00"},
 {"uid":464,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
 {"uid":493,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
 {"uid":76,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
 {"uid":505,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
 {"uid":506,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
 {"uid":494,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
 {"uid":495,"totalAmount":"180.00"}]
```

From this result I want to create a multidimensional array that will look like below:

```
[ 
    "0" =>
    [
        "0"=>["uid"=>29, "totalAmount"=>5400 ],
        "1"=>["uid"=>499, "totalAmount"=>5400]     
    ],

   "1" =>
   [
       "0"=>["uid"=>507, "totalAmount"=>3960 ],
       "1"=>["uid"=>497, "totalAmount"=>3960],
       "2"=>["uid"=>498, "totalAmount"=>3960 ],       
       "3"=>["uid"=>34, "totalAmount"=>3960],    
    ],
]
// and so on ...
```

I have tried with `foreach`:

```
 $topEar = [];

        $amount = '';

        foreach( $topEarners as $te)
        {    
            array_push($topEar, [$te->uid=>$te->totalAmount]);
        }

       $topEar;
```

Comment: How was your actual output different from your expected output?

Comment: The first string looks like json. Have you tried `json_decode()`? Also I don't understand how you get from the first string to the second one. Please clarify this.

Comment: I don't think this question deserve downvotes. So you need to group the values based on `totalAmount`? Why not adding `GROUP BY` to the query

Comment: @AlonEitan its  already group by with user id when pull the data and its object array.

Comment: You have multiple rows with the same user id?

Comment: Yes, @Mike I have multiple rows with the same user id

Comment: that isn't a php array to begin with..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$topEar = array();
$currAmountArray = array();
$amount = null;
foreach( $topEarners as $te) {
    if( !is_null($amount) && $te->totalAmount != $amount ) {
         array_push($topEar, $currAmountArray);
         $currAmountArray = array();
    }

    array_push($currAmountArray, $te);
    $amount = $te->totalAmount;
}
if( !empty($currAmountArray) ) {
   array_push($topEar, $currAmountArray);
}

print_r($topEar);
```

You're saving the last `$totalAmount` on each iteration and as long as it's not changing - you store the values in a sub-array called `$currAmountArray`, when the `$totalAmount` changes you push the values to the main array.

I also added a condition after the `foreach` loop, to make sure that the last bulk of data in `$currAmountArray` will also be pushed into the main array (which is `$topEar`).

Comment: Why should the OP "do something like this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Correct, i'm editing it now with some proper explenation

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the desired structure using SQL then this would be the easiest way in PHP:

```
$topEarners = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($topEarners as $row) {
    $result[$row['totalAmount']][] = $row;
}
```

- Decode the JSON into a PHP array
- Loop and append to an array using `totalAmount` as the key

If you want to reset the keys:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```